# How to keep data from same source shown on different screens synchronized

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, wcf-ria-services, mvvm-light

I have a scenario where at least 2 screens will be displayed at the same time that have the same source. On one screen this data is read-only, on other is editable. I need data on both screens to be synchronized. Also, data can be modified by different users.

Lets say that this is the sequence of actions:

1. user opens a screenA that contains read-only data from collectionA
2. User needs to add new items to collectionA, so screenB opens
3. user adds 3 new items on screenB, and then closes it
4. collection on screenA needs to have new items in it

There could be cases where more than 2 screens contain data from the same source (collection type).

I am using MVVM light and ViewModelLocator pattern to expose ViewModels to Views. Currently I fetch data in ViewModel's constructor. This means that if I cache ViewMOdel instance for reuse, I will fetch the data only once, all screens will use the same collection as source, so sync is done automatically. This also means that if other user on network changes data, new data will never be visible, since data is fetched only once (during ViewModel creation).

Another approach would be that ViewModelLocator returns new instance of ViewModel each time it is requested. This means that fresh data from database is always fetched, so issue with other network users changing data no longer exists. However, in this case each ViewModel will contain different instance of collection data, so only editing of data is being automatically synchronized, adding/deleting an entity is not being synchronized automatically.

So, what is the best way to have fresh data acquired when a ViewModel is requested, and also having data being synchronized between different screens?

Comment: Inject a SharedViewModel singleton containing the collection into each ViewModel that needs that data.

Comment: That way i will be able to share the same collection of data amongst different views. I am already doing something similar. But , if the SharedViewModel is singleton, how will it query for the fresh data? So far all my ViewModels are getting data in constructor, which means that SharedViewmodel would query the data only once, when constructed.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  I'll use DispatcherTimer to refresh data in SharedViewModel.  I also use Caliburn Micro so all my pages have lifecycle.  I might populate data in the OnInitialize method of a page or the OnActivate depending on my requirements.

Comment: Using DispatcherTimer leaves a bitter taste in mouth. Imagine that there is no view that currently references view model. Why would you want to query for data when timer elapses, if no view needs it? Also, querying for data should be the role of view model, not the page. Page itself should not have business logic to decide when data should be queried/refreshed.

Comment: I think the solution lies in having a reference counter on view model, so when none is using it, it should requery the data next time it is asked. Also, if reference count is greater than zero, then a timer could be a solution to fetch data. But I am not sure what is the best method to implement reference counting...

Comment: My views don't have any logic in them.  OnInitialize and OnActivate live in the ViewModel.  As matter of fact I delete the code behind or .xaml.cs files.  I use timers when they're needed, if a screen has a requirement for it.  The timer only active when the screen that requires it is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a poor job of explaining this in my comments so I created an [example](https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmdemo/src) of what I was talking about.  It's using CM but the idea can be transferred to MVVM-light.

I created 2 view models: `SharingScreen1ViewModel` and `SharingScreen2ViewModel` and 2 Views: `SharingScreen1View` and `SharingScreen2View`.

Each VM gets the SharedViewModel singleton injected.  From the left nav you can toggle between the 2 Views.  The `SharedDataViewModel` properties are initially set in the OnInitialize method that lives in `SharingScreen1ViewModel`.  Then the values can be changed in SharingScreen2ViewModel by clicking the button.  Toggle back to View one and the values have changed for it as well.

When I mentioned the DispatcherTimer, I was referring to a requirement I had to refresh a bit of data every 30 seconds.  The timer was one of many ways to update this data.  As you can see in this example the data is being set one time when the first ViewModel is initialized and the data is being set again in another ViewModel when the user clicks a button.

Interface `SharedViewModel` implements:

```
 public interface ISharedViewModel
    {
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
        string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

SharingScreen1ViewModel:

```
 [Export(typeof (SharingScreen1ViewModel))]
    public class SharingScreen1ViewModel : Screen
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public SharingScreen1ViewModel(ISharedViewModel sharedViewModel)
        {
            DisplayName = "Shared Data Screen 1";

            SharedViewModel = sharedViewModel;
        }

        public ISharedViewModel SharedViewModel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialize()
        {
            base.OnInitialize();

            SharedViewModel.FirstName = "Jimmy";
            SharedViewModel.LastName = "Hugh";
            SharedViewModel.Address = "555 South St.";
        }
    }
```

SharingScreen2ViewModel:

```
[Export(typeof (SharingScreen2ViewModel))]
    public class SharingScreen2ViewModel : Screen
    {
        [ImportingConstructor]
        public SharingScreen2ViewModel(ISharedViewModel sharedViewModel)
        {
            DisplayName = "Shared Data Screen 2";

            SharedViewModel = sharedViewModel;
        }

        public ISharedViewModel SharedViewModel { get; set; }

        public void ChangeSharedData()
        {
            SharedViewModel.FirstName = "New First Name";
            SharedViewModel.LastName = "New Last Name:";
            SharedViewModel.Address = "New Address";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Derek, thanks for the effort you provided. I am looking at your example, and it is not giving the answer to my question. By exporting the SharedViewModel as Shared, all synchronization works fine, since all ViewModels that use shared view work on the same data. The problem is how/when to refresh the SharedVIewModel data from database when using singleton ViewModels. A SharingScreen1ViewModel could also be used by several ViewModels, and will be used directly by View - this means that it will also be created only once. So, who will issue the request to refresh the data?

Comment: What is the requirement for when the data needs refreshed?

Comment: IMagine that SharedViewModel contains a ObsrevableCollection<>, and another user added a new item, so this view needs to have this item shown. Now, this doesn't need to happen immediately, but the idea is that if a new view is opened, it should query for a new data, and all other views should also get this data.

Comment: In SharingScreen1 I have code in OnInitialize.  To load data each time a new view is opened I'd use OnActivate instead.  Not sure if MvvmLight has that.

Comment: No, it doesnt. Do you by any chance know how is OnActivate implemented on Caliburn? And how it is working? If its fired like on View lostfocus/gotfocus, then its not adequate for this scenario...

Comment: Check this out.http://matthamilton.net/madprops-mvvmlight-screenconductor.  I use to use MvvmLight but switched when I started running into these type of problems.  Screens and conductors are wonderful.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Since I cannot go with Phil's solution due to multiple data loading from database, I am going to accept your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using MVVM Light's ViewModelLocator you presumably have code something like

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        // register your types with your favourite DI container
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get 
        { 
            var vm = // resolve singleton instance, data obtained in constructor
            return vm;
        }
    }
```

Would a simple change like this be sufficient for your requirements?

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    ...
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get 
        { 
            var vm = // resolve singleton instance
            vm.RefreshData(); // data obtained/updated here
            return vm;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Phil, I have a question regarding this solution. Since MainViewModel would be used in xaml binding, is it certain that this getter will be called only once (on InitializeComponent() call), and never again during the lyfecycle of the UI element? If yes, then this is acceptable solution.

Comment: I can't guarantee it won't be called more than once, but it shouldn't be if nothing explicitly calls OnPropertyChanged("Main") for example.

Comment: Each call to getter will result in new database query, so my concern. My question was pointed towards xaml side, if UI for some reason would call getter more than once. Currently I see no reason for WiewModelLocator to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so I am not implementing it.